# Express using typedi / di to store mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, dependencies

I'm trying to use typedi's container to store my model so i don't have to require the model file everytime I want to create a record.

Here's my current code that works using the require method.

```
 const DbService  = require('../db');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const  User  = require('../db/user.db');


const createUser = async (user) => {
    console.log('service');
    const newUser = {
      email:'test@test.com',
      salt: 'salt',
      password: 'password'
    };

    const createNew = new User(newUser);
    createNew.save().then(result=>{
     console.log('done');
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = {
  createUser
}
```

And my model file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // id int [pk,increment]
    email       : String,
    name        : String,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

How can i modify this following typedi's container documentation to do something like this.

```
const DbService  = require('../db');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// const  User  = require('../db/user.db');
const Container = require("typedi").Container;
const User      = Container.get(User);

const createUser = async (user) => {
    console.log('service');
    const newUser = {
      email:'test@test.com',
      salt: 'salt',
      password: 'password'
    };

    const createNew = new User(newUser);
    createNew.save().then(result=>{
     console.log('done');
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = {
  createUser
}
```